# Как заставить программу повторно просить ввести цифру при вводе любого другого символа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Нужно чтобы программа при вводе любого символа кроме цифры писала "Неправильно заданы значения" и снова просила ввести цифру.Должен использовать цикл while.
Код:

```
fnum=input("Введите 1 число : ")
try:
    int(fnum)
except ValueError:
    try:
        float(fnum)
    except ValueError:
        print("Неправильно заданы значения")
snum=input("Введите 2 число: ")
try:
    int(snum)
except ValueError:
    try:
        float(snum)
    except ValueError:
        print("Неправильно заданы значения")
arif=input("Введите арифметический знак: ")
if arif=="*":
    print(fnum*snum)
if arif=="/":
    print(fnum/snum)
if arif=="-":
    print(fnum-snum)
if arif=="+":
    print(fnum+snum)
else:
    print("Неправильно заданы значения")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Используйте этот код:

```
while True:
    fnum=input("Введите 1 число : ")
    try:
        int(fnum)
        break
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(fnum)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Неправильно заданы значения")
while True:
    snum=input("Введите 2 число: ")
    try:
        int(snum)
        break
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(snum)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Неправильно заданы значения")
while True:
    arif=input("Введите арифметический знак: ")
    if arif=="*":
        print(float(fnum)*float(snum))
        break
    elif arif=="/":
       print(float(fnum)/float(snum))
        break
    elif arif=="-":
        print(float(fnum)-float(snum))
        break
    elif arif=="+":
        print(float(fnum)+float(snum))
        break
    else:
        print("Неправильно заданы значения")
```

Comment: Бесконечно пишет неправильно заданы значения

Comment: простите, опечатка, щас исправлю

Comment: я исправил код.

Comment: За код нужно пояснять - что вы поменяли и почему это будет работать по-другому. Словами. Просто один код не даёт понимания - что же вы поменяли и почему это исправляет ошибку (если исправляет). Это нужно сравнивать два кода какой-то тулзой или глазами, что есть лишняя работа.

Comment: Это бесконечный цикл while true который будет работать до первого break, то есть до нормального ответа. Так же я поставил в некоторых местах elif.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что это надо писать в самом ответе - до кода и/или после кода, а возможно и в виде комментариев в коде тоже.

Comment: Хорошо, учту в следующий раз

Comment: Лучше бы прямо с этого раза начать. Вы можете редактировать ответ. Даже и принятый уже. )  Видите - кто-то вашему ответу минус поставил? Возможно, это как-раз из-за отсутствия пояснений.